# How increment through records when row number and id is out of sync?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, increment

When you have deleted some previous records in the DB, the auto-incremented record ID and the row number of the later records gets out of sync.

So, how do start from a given record and efficiently increment to the next record?

If you use the record ID, you might hit an ID that has been deleted.
If you use something like User.first(:offset => user_id) then you might miss some records. Since
on a given record the user_id might be higher than the row number (as a result of previous record(s) having been deleted).

The only solution I've found is to increment through all records each time,
but that seems very inefficient:

```
user_id = params[:id].to_i
users = User.all
next_user = nil
next_cond = false
users.each do |u|
  if u.id == user_id
    next_cond = true
  elsif next_cond
    next_user = a
    break
  end
end
```

So, how do you efficiently get the next record? 
Is there a way to get the row number of a given record, for instance?

NB: I am using SQLite locally, and MySQL on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
User.where("id > ?", user_id).order("id ASC").first
```

Comment: Thanks, that would work! It's so obvious when I see it.. But do I even need the order("id ASC") part, if the id column is auto-incremented? And, is there an even more efficient method than getting a resultset with all the remaining rows?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the order shouldn't be necessary. I really just put it there to make the logic of how this works obvious. I'm not sure I understand your second question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a pagination solution.

will_paginate is the best solution I'm familiar with, but it's kind of old, and I haven't checked in a while if a better one has come along.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/51-will-paginate

Comment: Yep there's Kaminari which is newer, but using a pagination library for just going to the next record is overkill.

Comment: ahh, true.  I was thinking he was going to step to the next record repeatedly (a.k.a. iterating).  If he's only going to step one ahead once, then ... yeah.  Overkill.  ... +1 Jakub

Comment: Thanks for a good suggestion, and teaching me about pagination :-) I had to accept Jakubs answer though since it was so simple and works well for my needs. I realize pagination has some overhead in the library, but I wonder if it would be more efficient on each call..